# worksheet in c#

Tags: c#, worksheet

I am using c# to write to excel file and to color the particular cell.
I am using the code as:

```
    Workbook wbook = new Workbook();
   Worksheet sheet1 = wbook.Worksheets[0];
  sheet1.Columns[j].Style.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepPink;
   wbook.SaveAs("E:\\new.xls");
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\\new.xls");
   wbook.Close();
```

but workbook is throwing an error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

can anyone help..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried do that with [NativeExcel](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcelnet/doc/NativeExcel.html) ?

I think it's very useful.

```
using System; 
using NativeExcel; 

 class Program { 
     static void Main(string[] args) { 
         //Create a new empty workbook. 
         IWorkbook book = NativeExcel.Factory.CreateWorkbook(); 

         //Create a new sheet in the workbook. 
         IWorksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add(); 

         //Set a value for cell A1
         sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = 300;  
         //Set a value for cell A2
         sheet.Cells[2,1].Value = 200;  
         //Set a formula for cell A3
         sheet.Cells["A3"].Formula = "=SUM(A1:A2)";  

         //Save workbook
         book.SaveAs("book.xls");                
     } 
 }
```